# Mysqli query are not fetching database values

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying with php 7.0 as everyone recommend me here to start with it as 5.6 has been depreveted . But after writing its code i am unable to fetch the values from database. what wrong i am doing here. thank you

//This is my aboutus page//

```
<div class="col-lg-10">
    <?php  include('config.php');
    $query = mysqli_query('select * from about ');
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    ?>

    <h5>
    <?php echo $row['about_desc'] ;?>
    <br>
    <br>
    <?php echo $row['about_desc1']; ?>
    <br>
    <br>
    <?php echo $row['about_desc2'] ;?>
    <br>
    <br>
    <?php echo $row['about_desc3'] ;?>
    <br>
    <br>
    <?php echo $row['about_desc4']; ?> 

    </h5>
    <hr class="featurrate-divider">
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="tab-1">
    <?php  include('config.php ');
    $query = mysqli_query('select * from news LIMIT 0,2');
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    ?>
    <div class="news">
        <h4><u><?php echo $row['news_name']; ?></u></h4>
        <h5><font color="black"><?php echo $row['dat']; ?></font></h5>

        <p><?php echo $row['news_desc']; ?></p>
        <a href="index.php?con=8">se mer >></a>
    </div>
    <hr class="featurrate-divider">

    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

//This is my config.php file//

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','dandelion') or die(mysqli_error($connection));
?>
```

Looking for good suggestion as a learner. thank you

Comment: `mysqli_query()` need first parameter as your connection!!

Comment: @Saty can you please explain me .thank you

Comment: Please remove everything that does *not* cause the problem. Right now you have bunch of html that has nothing to do with your question. Improve readability as much as you can if you want good answers!

Comment: okey i will @Al.G.

Comment: Use you query as `mysqli_query($connection,'select * from about ');`

Comment: try , mysqli_query($connection ,$query);

Comment: Thank you @Saty  you guys are genious,...... (y) thank you .

Comment: Thank you @DhavalDave you guys are genious,...... (y) thank you .

Comment: Thank you @Al.G. for your kinf suggestion for improving my question...... (y) thank you .

Answer (score 1):

**Your About us page should be like this:**

```
<body>

                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <?php  include('config.php');
                    $query = mysqli_query($connection, 'select * from about ');
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                       ?>

                         <h5>
                        <?php echo $row['about_desc'] ;?>
                                            <br>
                                                <br>
                                                    <?php echo $row['about_desc1']; ?>
                                                    <br>
                                                        <br>
                                                            <?php echo $row['about_desc2'] ;?>
                                                            <br>
                                                                <br>
                                                                    <?php echo $row['about_desc3'] ;?>
                                                                    <br>
                                                                        <br>
                                                                            <?php echo $row['about_desc4']; ?> 

                    </h5>
                    <hr class="featurrate-divider">
                                        <?php
                                        }
                                        ?>
                </div>
                </div>

                                <div id="tab-1">
                                     <?php  include('config.php ');
                                    $query = mysqli_query($connection, 'select * from news LIMIT 0,2');
                                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                                       ?>
                                    <div class="news">
                                        <h4><u><?php echo $row['news_name']; ?></u></h4>
                                         <h5><font color="black"><?php echo $row['dat']; ?></font></h5>

                                         <p><?php echo $row['news_desc']; ?></p>
                                        <a href="index.php?con=8">se mer >></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <hr class="featurrate-divider">

                                    <?php
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </div>



</body>
```

Comment: thank you @techie code.. yes i got my error.. thank you so much .

Answer (score 0):

if your database connection is sucessfully work and problem with fetching data than use number.it may be useful to fetch the data.

`<?php echo $row[o]; ?>`

```
<?php echo $row[1]; ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php echo $row['about_desc1']; ?>
```

Comment: actually i m wrong here in mysqli_query($connection ,$query); . I am missing the $connection .. thank you